# Mongodb Aggregate - How can i filter an array by multilpe array indexes?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I have a huge array and I need to get only array indexes that are multiple by 12. I thought using `$filter`, but I'm struggling in the `cond` parameter.

I'm using aggregate because there is more stuff that i need to do, but I'm stuck in this filter part.

```
data : [3,4,5,6,...,etc, <more 5000 items> ]
```

query:

```
db.test.aggregate([{$project:{filtered_values: {$filter:{input: '$data', as:data ,cond: { ??? some witchcraft ???}  }}}}])
```

Expected result:

```
[data[0],data[12],data[24],data[36],data[i%12 ===0]]
```

How can i reach this result with aggregate? Or if is `$filter` the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $map: {
               input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$data" }, 12] },
               as: "i",
               in: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data", "$$i"] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Solved pretty well! Thanks!

Comment: In this case, please accept the answer.